# How to get spell checking in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, spell-checking

In my application I want to check if the word entered is correct or not. I searched for spell checking examples but I didn't find any examples.

Comment: i just want to implement spell check functionality i tried for examples but i didn't find.I tried by using searchable dictionary example in sample but there are only 999 words is it possible to get default google dictionary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think android provides a Spell Check service by default.

Assuming that you didn't look for it in the developer website,

here goes the link,

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spell-checker-framework.html

Also it looks like the examples are available with the sdk package itself.

Comment: Thanks for your response but how to find example in that location