# Android Edittext: when contains misspelling word (with red underline over it), do not allow to submit

Tags: android, android-edittext, misspelling

I am recently making my first Android App and it has a `Edittext` area which plans to only allow users to input correctly spelled words. Basically I have already learned how to use layout properties such as `Android:inputType` to detect any misspelled words. Any misspelled words should be marked with a red underline. But I cannot find a way to prevent users from inputting misspelled words.

The ideal situation is: if a user has input any misspelled words and clicks the submit button, a prompt message (for example a Toast message) would appear to inform the user to modify misspelled words before they can really submit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897020/how-to-get-spell-checking-in-android. check out this link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Follow steps from this link to create a spelling checker.**
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_spelling_checker.htm

**Then modify the sample code above to meet your requirement:** 
E.g. When (arg0.length == 0), that means there is no suggestion (no spelling mistake), you can create validation from here. 
However, it could be a word that is not written in English. So you would need a language detection:

https://code.google.com/p/language-detection/
(From: [How to detect language of user entered text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227524/how-to-detect-language-of-user-entered-text))

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do to achieve this is  implement spellchecksession listener.
May be you can use spell check listener along with a text watcher.

[SpellCheckListener](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_spelling_checker.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to validate word(Spell check).

```
public boolean CheckForWord(String Word){
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/usr/share/dict/american-english"));
        String str;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            if ( str.indexOf( Word) != -1 ) {
                return true;
            } 
        }
        in.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
    }

return false;
}
```

And on SUBMIT Button Click

```
btnSUBMIT.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             String EdittextValue = edittext.getText().toString();
              if(CheckForWord(EdittextValue)){
              Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                    "Correct Word " + EdittextValue ,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              // Do something here.
            }
           else{
             Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                    "Wrong Word " + EdittextValue ,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
           }
        });
```